# Grant user with select privileges

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-grant

I just create a new user name `TEST`

```
CREATE USER TEST IDENTIFIED BY 123;
```

My database;

```
TABLE1
------------
--data

TABLE2
-----------
--data
```

Now I want to allow user `test` can give select permission to other users on table 2 only.

How can I grant the privileges so that user `TEST` can give only select statement for other users on table2?

Comment: Can't test atm, but `GRANT SELECT ON TABLE2 TO TEST WITH GRANT OPTION` seems like it would work.

Comment: I dont have an environment to test yet. Can you try something like this GRANT SELECT ON table2 TO test WITH GRANT OPTION;